Launching an external installer with wix v5
I made a wpf application and I am using an external application (here npp).I want to create a setup file with wix v5 and install the external application with it. I'm very new to wix and I'm having a hard time finding resources.
I added the ExampleComponents.wxs file and the exe of my external installer as follows, but I couldn't figure out how to start it.
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ExampleComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Files Include="C:\Users\User1\Desktop\firstRunLab\firstRunLab\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows\**" />
      <File Source="C:\Users\User1\Downloads\npp.8.6.6.Installer.x64.exe" Id="ExternalInstaller" />
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>



Are you sure it's 8.6.6 and not 8.0.6?

You could do this by adding a CustomAction with defined ExeCommand and calling it after ExitDlg finish in your msi docu here.
BUT, the better approach is definitely to create a WiX bundle to install your application and npp docu here.
